# Changing the visibility of a widget from a thread (concurrent.futures), don't work in normal mode, in debug mode it works, why?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I wanted to change the visibility of a rect in my gui. Therefore i use a endless while in a thread but it does't work (only in debug mode). Do somebody have he answer?

Can you help me to finish my idea or give me a tip to do the work in a other way?

At the end I wand to check the ethernet connection and show it by an green or red rect. For testing i am sending a specified message to a server which sends back a answer.

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from concurrent import futures
from time import sleep


class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        # configure the main window
        self.setWindowTitle('Msg Tool')
        self.resize(230, 330)

        # Check if ethernet is ok
        self.close_connection_test = [0]

        self.e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        self.e.submit(self.connection_test)

        # RedRect
        self.red_rect = RedRect(self)
        self.red_rect.move(180, 12.5)
        self.red_rect.setVisible(True)

        # GreenRect
        self.green_rect = GreenRect(self)
        self.green_rect.move(180, 12.5)
        self.green_rect.setVisible(False)

    # Function called at the end of the application
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close_connection_test = [1]  # To stop the endless loop in the task
        self.e.shutdown()  # Shutdown the executer

    def connection_test(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            if self.close_connection_test == [1]:
                break
            if (i % 2) == 0:
                self.red_rect.setVisible(False)
            else:
                self.red_rect.setVisible(True)
            # self.red_rect.setVisible(False)
            print('Test')
            sleep(1)


class RedRect(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RedRect, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.pen.setWidth(1)
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 48, 48))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 15, 15)


class GreenRect(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GreenRect, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.pen.setWidth(1)
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(124, 252, 0))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 15, 15)


Application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Application.setStyle('Fusion')
inst_MainApplication = MainApplication()
inst_MainApplication.show()

sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey eyllanesc, you are right. The problem was that i used the red rect before i created it in the init function. I tested your solution with the qEvent it works very good. In the future i will test the other solution, too. Thank you very much for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must use submit after creating self.red_rect because if you are not going to see an error stating that the attribute does not exist.

```py
class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        # configure the main window
        self.setWindowTitle('Msg Tool')
        self.resize(230, 330)

        # RedRect
        self.red_rect = RedRect(self)
        self.red_rect.move(180, 12.5)
        self.red_rect.setVisible(True)

        # GreenRect
        self.green_rect = GreenRect(self)
        self.green_rect.move(180, 12.5)
        self.green_rect.setVisible(False)

        # Check if ethernet is ok
        self.close_connection_test = [0]
        self.e = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        self.e.submit(self.connection_test)
```

On the other hand the problem is that you should not update the GUI from another directly but through pyqtSignal, `QMetaObject::invokedMethod()`, QEvent, or the simplest way using `QTimer::singleShot()` with `functools.partial()`:

#### 1. QTimer

```py
# ...
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# ...
class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...
    def connection_test(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            if self.close_connection_test == [1]:
                break
            isVisible = i % 2 != 0
            wrapper = partial(self.red_rect.setVisible, isVisible)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
            print('Test')
            sleep(1)
```

#### 2. pyqtSignal

```py
class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    visibilityChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...


        # RedRect
        self.red_rect = RedRect(self)
        self.red_rect.move(180, 12.5)
        self.red_rect.setVisible(True)
        self.visibilityChanged.connect(self.red_rect.setVisible)

        # ...

    def connection_test(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            if self.close_connection_test == [1]:
                break
            isVisible = i % 2 != 0
            self.visibilityChanged.emit(isVisible)
            print('Test')
            sleep(1)
# ...
```

#### 3. QMetaObject::invokedMethod

```
# ...
def connection_test(self):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if self.close_connection_test == [1]:
            break
        isVisible = i % 2 != 0
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
            self.red_rect,
            "setVisible",
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
            QtCore.Q_ARG(bool, isVisible),
        )
        print("Test")
        sleep(1)
# ...
```

#### 4. QEvent

```py
class CustomEvent(QtCore.QEvent):
    _type = QtCore.QEvent.User

    def __init__(self, visibility):
        super(CustomEvent, self).__init__(CustomEvent._type)
        self._visibility = visibility

    @property
    def visibility(self):
        return self._visibility

class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...

    def connection_test(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1
            if self.close_connection_test == [1]:
                break
            isVisible = i % 2 != 0
            event = CustomEvent(isVisible)
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(self, event)
            print("Test")
            sleep(1)

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() == CustomEvent._type:
            self.red_rect.setVisible(e.visibility)
            return True
        return super(MainApplication, self).event(e)
```